# Apache - Adding a URL redirect via Proxy Server

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy

Is it possible to redirect a user to a specific link over a proxy connection?

Example, Whenever a user visits the apache server ip address:

```
http://196.169.34.34
```

apache should redirect the user to a specific url link **via** a proxy server(**196.169.34.21**) on a specific port, port **3128**

is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the vhost config for `196.169.34.34`, you can add:

```
Redirect / http://196.169.34.21:3128/specific-url
```

Replacing the `specific-url` part with the URL you want the browser to be redirected to.

If you don't have vhost config access, you can add a rewrite rule to the htaccess file in your document root (assuming you have the proper overrides for an htaccess file and mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^196\.169\.34\.34$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://196.169.34.21:3128/specific-url/(.*)$ [L,R]
```

You can make this redirect permanent by adding a 301:

```
Redirect 301 / http://196.169.34.21:3128/specific-url
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^196\.169\.34\.34$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://196.169.34.21:3128/specific-url/(.*)$ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you so much. This seems if it can work, I will test it and let you know. One question though, on a Windows System, where do I find the vhost config file?

Comment: I do have access to the vhost config file and I added this line: Redirect / http://196.169.34.21:3128/specific-url. But in the browser, it redirects to this whole url not just the 'specific-url' part via the proxy...

Comment: @DextrousDave if you don't want the requested URI to carry over in the redirect change it to: `RedirectMatch / http://196.169.34.21:3128/specific-url` instead, essentially using `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using a Local solution - Proxy PAC file on the local PC. The function of this file is to direct certin traffic, based on a URL/URI, to direct to a certain proxy address, like in my example.

Here is sample code of the .pac file. You can get the full documentation [here](http://www.proxypacfiles.com/proxypac/):

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

// First start with the exceptions that need to be proxied

if ((host == "www.company.net") ||
    (host == "webmail.company.net") ||
    (host == "portal.company.net") ||
    (dnsDomainIs(host, ".public.company.net"))) {
         return "PROXY proxy1.company.net:8000";
}

// Next, we want to send all traffic to company.net browser direct

if (dnsDomainIs(host, ".company.net")) {
       return "DIRECT";
}

// Default return condition is the proxy, since it’s assumed that everything
// else is on the Internet.

return "PROXY proxy1.company.net:8000";

} // End of function
```

THis is how you actually call the proxy.pac file from your internet options on Windows:

[image]